# Use auto_incremented ID in same statement the ID is being created

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure how to formulate the title correctly. I'll try to elaborate, and make it understandable here.

I have a table with an auto_incremented ID (Primary Key). In the same table I have a guid-column. This guid is going to be an URL. So the guid will typically be something like http://www.example.com/path/path/ID

My question is this:
Because the ID is auto-generated on INSERT, and I don't manually assign this, I dont know beforehand what the ID is going to be. How can I then assign the guid-value in the insert-statement, if I'm dependant on having the ID?

The solution I have at the moment is doing it with two statements:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, guid) 
VALUES (null, null);
```

I will now have a row that looks something like this:

```
-------------
| ID | GUID |
-------------
| 1  | null |
-------------
```

I can then in another statement update this row with a statement like this;

```
UPDATE  table SET  guid = ID WHERE ID = 1;
```

(Might be off-syntax, but you get the point)

Is there any way to do this in "one go"? Where I can set the GUID based off of what the auto_incremented ID is going to be? So it would be something like this

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, guid) 
VALUES (null, ID);
```

I hope my question is understandable! I will clarify if it's still unclear. I don't know any better way to explain my question.

Comment: If the id has some kind of meaning beyond the scope of the database, then you shouldn't really be using auto_increment for this. AUTO_INCREMENT is great for surrogate keys, but that's about it. That said, if we have the path and the PK, what do we need the GUID for?

Comment: The table is a pre-made wordpress table (wp_posts). The ID is being used as a unique identifier for each row, and it's also being used as part of the URL that's being stored in the GUID. Apart from this, the ID does not have a usage, or a meaning.

Comment: As you have defined it, `ID` will always be equal to `GUID`.  Therefore the `GUID` field will always be redundant and unnecessary.  Wouldn't it be better to develop a path, (assuming PHP) like `$guid = "http://www.example.com/path/path/".$row['id'];` where `$row['id']` is the result from your query?

Answer (score 1):

If the PK is autogenerated you don't need it in your insert query.

```
insert into table
(guid)
values
(your guid)
```

You of course have to generate the guid on your own and there are lots of ways to do that.